# How to deal with memory error: for doing a decoder

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, data-science, encoder, decoder

```
decoder_targets_one_hot = np.zeros((
        len(input_sentences),
        max_out_len,
        num_words_output
    ),
    dtype='float32'
)
```

I am getting a memory error in the line dtype='float32'. I am stuck in this. How to get through this?

Comment: Please post the full traceback so we can see the exact error. What is the length of the list?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case it would help if you post a [mre] and the complete stacktrace.

Comment: When you ask a quesiton, please follow up with the questions we ask you. Knowing the size of the array you are trying to create is a critical part of the question. You've got multiple people who will engage on this but now it seems like you are just wasting our time.

Answer (score 0):

The `ndarray` you are trying to initiate is too large when using `float32` as the datatype. Either reduce the dimension size or get more ram.